# AzureApp HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Tags: azure, .net-6.0, azure-appservice

***Works locally but NOT on Azure AppService***

Using: Visual Studio 2022
Asp.Net MVC .NET 6
AzureApp Platform: Windows 32/bit
[image]
My App is a sample
I went through through from [AzureAppSample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app?pivots=platform-linux&tabs=azure-cli%2Cvisualstudio-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azcli%2Cazure-portal-logs%2Cazure-portal-resources#1---set-up-the-sample-application)

I am able to run it locally on mymachine. It is when I deploy to Azure using Visual Studio 2022 and then view my public URL that I get the error. When I look at the logs in Azure using Kudu I find "**`Application ...../ROOT' with physical root 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message: CLR worker thread exited prematurely</Data>`**"

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your configuration so that you can get a better idea of what the error is:

ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS = 1

Comment: Thanks got it to work. The error exposed "FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices, Version=6.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified." Then I updated my Visual Studio since AzureApp uses latest.